# rspec: undefined method 'double'

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec2

I'm trying to create a double but I keep getting this error:

```
 undefined method `double' for #<Class:0x007fa48c234320> (NoMethodError)
```

I suspect the problem has got to do with my spec helper so I'm adding my spec helper below:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'rspec'
require 'webmock/rspec'
include WebMock::API
include WebMock::Matchers

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
end
```

Comment: where / how are you calling double ?

Comment: within my describe `block` before the `it` block.

Comment: double exists inside examples (and before() blocks etc) but it sounds like you're trying to call it outside one of those contexts.

Comment: @FrederickCheung it works now. thanks! i shall go read up to reenforce some understanding.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: perhaps you could make an answer from your commment so this question is not left unanswered.

Comment: Sure, why not. maybe it will help some lost soul

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`double` exists inside examples (and `before` blocks etc) but it sounds like you're trying to call it outside one of those contexts.

So for example

```
describe Thing do
  thing = double()
  it 'should go bong'
  end
end
```

is incorrect but

```
describe Thing do
  before(:each) do
    @thing = double()
  end

  it 'should go bong' do
    other_thing = double()
  end
end
```

is fine

Answer (score 9):

You can also use RSpec's `double` outside of RSpec by requiring the standalone file.

```
require "rspec/mocks/standalone"

greeter = double("greeter")
allow(greeter).to receive(:say_hi) { "Hello!" }
puts greeter.say_hi
```

From the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/outside-rspec/standalone

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks.